# MSI GS60 with Killer wireless 1525 can't suspend or shutdown

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, network-manager

I am having a problem. I just can't suspend laptop or shutdown, it gets stuck. I narrowed down the cause and it appears it is wireless card, Killer 1525. Now I am on Ubuntu 18.10, kernel 4.18, everything is updated to newest current version on newest firmware 1.175, but the problem persist. Previously I was on ubuntu 18.04, had same problem. I also tried files in this repository: https://github.com/kvokka/msi_gs60/tree/master/wifi. I also tried given files in Killer webpage: https://www.killernetworking.com/killersupport/driver-downloads/kb/cat/6-linux#faq_80, but that too didn't help...

This is excerpt from kernel log, after I close the lid:

```
Oct  9 19:18:15 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  128.693478] Call Trace:
Oct  9 19:18:15 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  128.693471] wpa_supplicant  D    0   880      1 0x00000004
Oct  9 19:18:15 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  128.693336] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.003 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
Oct  9 19:18:15 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  127.808445] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e017 <keycode>' to make it known.
Oct  9 19:18:15 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  127.808437] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x97 on isa0060/serio0).
Oct  9 19:18:15 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  127.805531] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e017 <keycode>' to make it known.
Oct  9 19:18:15 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  127.805524] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0x97 on isa0060/serio0).
Oct  9 19:18:15 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.689468] Freezing user space processes ... 
Oct  9 19:18:15 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.646879] rfkill: input handler enabled
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.403227] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to delete WMI vdev 1: -108
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.403192] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.285067] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.285065] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272631] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000   1   1   1   1
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272621] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00  15  15  15  15
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272612] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800   0   0   0   0
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272603] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 833 833 226 162
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272593] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000   7   7   8   7
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272584] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00  44  44 107 108
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272575] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800   2   2  37  38
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272565] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400   1   1   3   3
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272555] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272553] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [56]: 0x809A6C34 0x0041A8E0 0x0042932C 0x0042CA44
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272550] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [52]: 0x800B4405 0x0041A850 0x00422318 0x00005002
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272548] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [48]: 0x80996BD3 0x0041A830 0x0044FD68 0x00000000
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272545] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [44]: 0x80992076 0x0041A810 0x0044FD68 0x0046FFE8
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272543] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [40]: 0x8099638C 0x0041A7F0 0x00404D88 0x00000000
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272540] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [36]: 0x809BDECC 0x0041A7D0 0x00404D88 0x0040E074
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272538] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [32]: 0x80947BA7 0x0041A7B0 0x00404D88 0x0040E074
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272535] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [28]: 0x80942BC4 0x0041A790 0x42D0B71D 0x00400000
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272533] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [24]: 0x809432A7 0x0041A770 0x0040D400 0xC092E4DC
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272531] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [20]: 0x4092E4DC 0x0041A710 0x00000000 0x0F000000
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272528] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [16]: 0x0096BDBC 0x009286B6 0x00000000 0x00000000
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272525] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x0096C09C 0x0096C0A7
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272523] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [08]: 0x42D0B71D 0x00400000 0x00000000 0x000A5C88
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272520] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [04]: 0x0092E4DC 0x00060130 0x00000018 0x0041A760
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272518] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [00]: 0x05010000 0x00000000 0x0092E4DC 0x42D0B731
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.272512] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware register dump:
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.270500] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.270497] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 ae2e275a
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.270310] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware ver SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 5 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 10bf8e08
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.269927] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.269925] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: qca6174 hw2.1 target 0x05010000 chip_id 0x003405ff sub 1a56:1525
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.269916] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid 2c6b9eda-95ac-4f33-b915-414326bdcc36)
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.269913] wlp5s0: failed to remove key (0, a7:57:58:05:ad:44) from hardware (-110)
Oct  9 19:17:55 linuxtownLaptop kernel: [  108.269908] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to install key for vdev 0 peer a7:57:58:05:ad:44: -110
```

What could I try next? I can't use my laptop if I can't put it to sleep.
I have killer wireless 1525.
My card in lshw command

product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter

vendor: Qualcomm Atheros

And if I try to shutdown, this is what I see on screen and have to force shutdown:
[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTMgu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same/similar issue with QCA6174. Ubuntu will hang on attempt to suspend while Wireless is enabled.  If I disable wireless, and try to suspend, then everything works normally.